# How do I use structs to take in user input to pass to another method?

Tags: c

I am trying to create a struct to take in user input in my main method so that I can pass it for later use. I have looked through the site for struct help, but what I've seen is that people try to create it as it's own function; I want to include it as part of my main. Here are some details for what I am trying to implement for my alarm clock:

1. Take in user input for the desired alarm time
2. Compare it to the local time
3. Decrement the timer in seconds, and print when it reaches the alarm

I am getting a slight compilation error regarding redeclaration/undeclared vars. Here's my progress thus far!

```
#include <time.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <termios.h>
#include <signal.h>

struct sc_alarm_struct{
int uhour, uminute, usecond;};

struct sc_alarm_struct am;
void sc_alarm();

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{  
  if (argc > 1)
    {
        am.uhour = atoi(argv[1]);  
        am.uminute = atoi(argv[2]);
        am.usecond = atoi(argv[3]);
  }
}

void sc_alarm(int uhour, int uminute, int usecond)
{

  struct tm *tm;
  time_t ctime;
  ctime = time(NULL);
  tm = localtime(&ctime);

  int alarm_total;
  int local_time_total;
  int difference;

  int chour = tm->tm_hour;
  int cminute = tm->tm_min;
  int csecond = tm->tm_sec;

  alarm_total = (uhour * 3600) + (uminute * 60) + usecond;
  local_time_total = (chour * 3600) + (cminute * 60) + csecond;
  difference = alarm_total - local_time_total;

  do
  {
    printf("%d seconds remaining.\n", difference);       
    difference--;
    sleep(1);
  }
  while(!(chour == am.uhour && cminute == am.uminute && csecond == am.usecond));

printf("\nAlarm reached, wake up!\n\n");

}
```

Any suggestions or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: To run (h m s represent the uhour, uminute, usecond with the aclock file), the format is: > aclock h m s ct

Comment: what is the exact compile error you are getting?

Answer (score 0):

It would be better if you can provide your build information so that others can see more details. As to this question, alarm() is a function defined in unistd.h(man 3 alarm, you will see), and you are not allowed to declare a variable by this name, and, what's that 'u' in line 51?

Comment: This isn't an answer. put a comment under the question.

Comment: You're totally correct and I made the according changes. To run (h m s represent the uhour, uminute, usecond), the format is: rohan> aclock h m s ct

Answer (score 0):

It is apparent your biggest challenge is getting comfortable with the struct syntax and passing structs as parameters to functions. Both are relatively easy. When you have a `struct` (not *pointer-to-struct*), you use the `'.'` (dot operator) to access each member. When you have a *pointer-to-struct*, you will use the `'->'` (arrow operator) to access each member. Those are your only two access rules for structs.

Passing structs as parameters, you can either pass a struct, e.g.

```
void sc_alarm (struct sc_alarm_struct astruct)
```

Which is what you will hear termed *pass-by-value*, which will pass the struct to the function, where the function will receive a *copy* of the struct. Any changes made to the struct member values *will Not* be reflected back in the calling function -- because you were operating on a *copy* where each value had a different address than it did back in `main`.

You can pass a pointer to the struct as a parameter, e.g.

```
void sc_alarm (struct sc_alarm_struct *astruct)
```

Here the function receives a pointer to your original struct. While it may also be a *copy*, since it is a pointer, the copy still points to the original member element addresses. Any changes made now will be reflected in the struct values back in the caller.

Since you are not *changing* the member values in your `sc_alarm` function, it doesn't matter which you use.

Your next issue was one of what to include within the scope of you `do {...} while (...);` loop. This choice is generally made by what must be visible outside the loop. If nothing is needed outside the loop, you can declare all your values within the loop. However, in your case you need `chour`, etc.. in the `while (test)`, so those must be declared outside of the loop itself.

Putting that altogether, and avoiding the unnecessary use of a *global* `struct sc_alarm_struct am;` you could do something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

struct sc_alarm_struct
{ int uhour, uminute, usecond; };

void sc_alarm (struct sc_alarm_struct *astruct);

int main (int argc, char **argv)
{  
    struct sc_alarm_struct am;

    /* time from parameters (default 12:15:45) */
    am.uhour   = argc > 1 ? atoi (argv[1]) :  0;  
    am.uminute = argc > 2 ? atoi (argv[2]) : 49;
    am.usecond = argc > 3 ? atoi (argv[3]) : 15;

    sc_alarm (&am);

    return 0;  /* main is type (int) and provides a return */
}

void sc_alarm (struct sc_alarm_struct *astruct)
{
    int alarm_total, local_time_total, difference,
        chour, cminute, csecond;

    do {
        struct tm *tm;
        time_t ctime;
        ctime = time (NULL);
        tm = localtime (&ctime);

        chour = tm->tm_hour;
        cminute = tm->tm_min;
        csecond = tm->tm_sec;

        alarm_total = (astruct->uhour * 3600) + 
                      (astruct->uminute * 60) + 
                       astruct->usecond;

        local_time_total = (chour * 3600) + 
                           (cminute * 60) + 
                            csecond;

        if (local_time_total > alarm_total) {
            fprintf (stderr, "error: alarm time is in the past.\n");
            exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
        difference = alarm_total - local_time_total;

        printf ("\r %4d seconds remaining.", difference);
        fflush (stdout);
        difference--;
        sleep (1);
    }
    while (!(chour   == astruct->uhour && 
            cminute == astruct->uminute && 
            csecond == astruct->usecond));

    printf ("\nAlarm reached, wake up!\n\n");
}
```

Now the countdown to the time will occur on a single line (presuming you don't set your alarm in the past) and then exit when the alarm is reached, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/alarm 0 56 30
    0 seconds remaining.
Alarm reached, wake up!
```

Give it a try and let me know if that is what you intended. If not, I'm happy to try again.